# Sorting vector keeps modifying data and prints incorrect results

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

So my code basically maps a students ID and Name to his or her grade and many functions and consists of internal functions which allows you to search for a particular student by grade, ID etc.

One particular function I'm trying to implement is something that prints the grade of all the inputted students in descending order.

## Program Class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class student{
public:
student();
student(int,string);
int id;
string name;
};

class table{
public:
void InsertStudent(student x, int y);
void PrintAll(table t);
void SearchbyID(student x);
void SearchbyGrade(int y); 
void SortbyGrade(table t);


private:
map<student, int > records;

};
```

## Main function

```
int main (){
table t;
string command;
int id;
string name;
int grade;
student x;
while ( cin >> command ){

if (command=="InsertStudent"){

cin >> id >> name>> grade;

student s(id,name);
t.InsertStudent(s,grade);
}else if (command == "PrintAll"){
t.PrintAll(t);
}else if (command == "SearchbyID"){
cin >> x.id;
t.SearchbyID(x);
}else if (command == "SearchbyGrade"){
cin >> grade;
t.SearchbyGrade(grade);
}
else if (command == "SortbyGrade"){
t.SortbyGrade(t);
}
else if (command == "exit"){
return 0;
 }
 }
}
```

## SortbyGrade Function

To simplify the same, I included the following struct.

```
struct information{
string id;
string name;
string grade;
};

void table::SortbyGrade(table t){
map<student,int>::iterator itr;
information a;
vector<information> v;
for(itr=records.begin();itr!=records.end();itr++)
{
    a.id=(*itr).first.id;
    a.name=(*itr).first.name;
    a.grade=(*itr).second;
    v.push_back(a);
}
vector<information>::iterator itr2;
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),compare);
for(itr2=v.begin();itr2!=v.end();itr2++){
    cout<<(*itr2).id<<" "<<(*itr2).name<<" "<<(*itr2).grade<<endl;
}
}
```

In this segment of code, I'm basically copying the key and the values from the map on to the vector to implement the sort algorithm

## Comparison function for descending sort

```
bool compare(const information &a, const information & b){
if(a.grade>b.grade)
    return true;
else if(a.grade<b.grade)
    return false;
 else 
    return a.id<b.id;
}
```

## Sameple Input and Output

Input

InsertStudent 2016001 David 97

InsertStudent 2016002 Alice 88

InsertStudent 2016003 Jackson 100

InsertStudent 2016004 Eric 60

InsertStudent 2016005 John 97

InsertStudent 2016006 Michael 79

Output

Jackson d

David a

John a

Alice X

Michael O

Eric

This indicates the sort is being performed correctly, however the information seems to have been altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a minimal example for you to reproduce the behavior:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    s = 100;
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Before you read further, can you figure out the reason on your own now?

`std::string::operator=` has a few overloads, and the one that fits the most here is `std::string::operator=(char ch)`. 100 is ASCII code for `'d'` so that is what Jackson's grade turns into when you assign its value to a `string grade` in your `information` struct.